# Add a connection string to local user config file throws lock exception

Tags: c#, configuration, entity-framework-5, sql-server-ce, app-config

I have developed a WinForm C# app that use ADO.NET Entity Framework for storing data.

I would like each user to have a database stored in their appdata\local folder but when I try to add the connection string to the users local app.config file I constantly get the error "**ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked.**"

After I did some research I discovered the *allowExeDefinition* section setting. 
I tried adding this setting for the connectionString section in the app.config file and at runtime (see code below) but I still get the same error whenever I try to save the configuration.

This is the code I use:

```
var connectionString = string.Format(ConnectionStringBase, dbLocation);

var exeConf = ConfigurationManager
   .OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

var connectionStringSettings = 
    new ConnectionStringSettings(
        "DatabaseEntities",
        connectionString,
        ProviderName);

exeConf.ConnectionStrings
    .SectionInformation
    .AllowExeDefinition = ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToLocalUser;

exeConf.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(connectionStringSettings);
exeConf.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

I have tried to search for a solution for this issue for days but I haven't been able to find anything usefull besides that I am considering storing the connection string in the users settings instead as a workaround but it feels kinda hackish.

Comment: Suggest another approach, see this: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: @ErikEJ Looks interesting but I'm not able to locate the _Visual Studio Installer Project_. The only option I've got is _InstallShield Limited Edition Project_.

Comment: Download the latest beta of that product, and use that instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, instead of updating the app.config file I decided to create the connectionstring on runtime and pass it to the entity set constructor.

So when I initialize the entity set I use the following code instead:

```
var connectionString = string.Format(ConnectionStringBase, dbLocation);

var entities = new DatabaseEntities(connectionString);
```

The only thing to note is that if the connection string contains *"* you should replace these with single quotes ( ' ).